# Reference for a commutative diagram

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

How to give a number (for later reference) to the following diagram?

```
\begin{displaymath}
\xymatrix@!C{ \{ \prod_{g \in A} \OO_g  \} \ar@{->>}[r] & {
\{\prod_{g \in A^{\prime}} \OO_g \} }\\ { {\tilde {\T}}^{\prime}_{
{\tilde{\m}}^{\prime} } } \ar@{^{(}->}[u] \ar@{->>}[r]^(0.55){q} &
{\T} \ar@{^{(}->}[u] }
\end{displaymath}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Here's [starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, the simplest way might be:

- if you'd like to number this along with other equations, put this inside an `equation` environment (instead of `displaymath`)
- if you'd like to number this with a custom number, put this inside an `equation*` and use `\tag{<your-label-here>}`.

And, to get the number centered, the trick is to center the number. So, this might go inside a `gathered` environment.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xypic} %generates a warning, but the problem is with the package
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered} 
\xymatrix@!C{ 
\left\{\prod_{g \in A}\mathcal{O}_g\right\} \ar@{->>}[r] 
& \left\{\prod_{g \in A^{\prime}} \mathcal{O}_g \right\} \ 
\widetilde{\mathcal{T}}}^{\prime}_{{\tilde{\mu}}^{\prime} \ar@{^{(}->}[u] \ar@{->>}[r]^(0.55){q} 
& {\mathcal{T}} \ar@{^{(}->}[u]
}
\end{gathered} 
\end{document}
```

Now, brace yourself as you see the output:

### [image: xypicdraw.png]

**Unrelated to your actual question**:

1. You seem to be having big symbols inside smaller braces. You might want to put this into `\left\{...\right\}`. (There are other variants here: the constructs `\bigl...\bigr` and `\biggl...\biggr` can be used the way one uses `\left...\right`.)
2. However, I'd suggest that you draw diagrams in Tikz, if you'd like to see beautiful images. (The package [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) is very good at this!)

Comment: Can you compile and see where the equation no. occurs. I want the number to apper at the right side of the diagram (that also to be in the centre). Thanks.  \begin{equation*}\tag{1}
\xymatrix@!C{A   &   B \ar[l]}\C& D \ar[l] \ar[u] }
\end{equation}

Comment: @ Kan: Thanks for all your comments. Yes. Gathered comment really helped. Still have a small problem. Equation no. appears left side (@ center as i wanted) but i want it to be rightside.   \begin{equation*}\tag{1}
\begin{gathered}\xymatrix@!C{A   &   B \ar[l]}\D& E \ar[l] \ar[u] }
\end{gathered}\end{equation}

Comment: @sri You can do that by passing the option `[reqno]` to your documentclass: eg, `\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}`.

Comment: Yes. It helped. I can't vote your answers (not having 15 points). Many thanks. I did mark the answer as right by clicking on the tick mark.